# Nginx with proxying behind port forwarding gateway

Tags: nginx

Nginx is set up in a local network and listens on port 80. It also can be accessed from the internet via a corporate gateway with public IP, but by a non-standard port, something like this: `public_ip:56480 --> local_ip:80`

Nginx proxies request to the application on the same machine, but to another port.

1. Client requests `http://public_ip:56480/`
2. Gateway forwards the request to internal Nginx to `http://local_ip:80/`
3. Nginx proxies the request to an application on another port on the same machine. To `http://localhost:9000/`
4. The application answers with a redirect (302) to `/secure/login`
5. **But** as a result browser is redirected to `http://public_ip/secure/login` without a port. But I need this `http://public_ip:56480/secure/login`

Here is output of wget -S command

```
user@machine:~$ wget -S http://x.x.x.x:56480
--2023-03-24 22:16:27--  http://x.x.x.x:56480/
Connecting to x.x.x.x:56480... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Fri, 24 Mar 2023 21:16:27 GMT
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 0
  Connection: keep-alive
  Location: http://x.x.x.x/secure/login
  Set-Cookie: PLAY_ERRORS=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Fri, 24 Mar 2023 21:16:27 GMT; Path=/
  Set-Cookie: PLAY_FLASH=url=%2F; Path=/
  Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Fri, 24 Mar 2023 21:16:27 GMT; Path=/
  Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://x.x.x.x/secure/login [following]
--2023-03-24 22:16:27--  http://x.x.x.x/secure/login
Connecting to x.x.x.x:80... connected.
............
```

Here is my Nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:9000/ /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

**UPD**

Output for `curl -I --location http://x.x.x.x:56480`

```
user@host:~$ curl -I --location http://x.x.x.x:56480
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 16:41:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://x.x.x.x/secure/login
Set-Cookie: PLAY_ERRORS=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sat, 25 Mar 2023 16:41:08 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_FLASH=url=%2F; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sat, 25 Mar 2023 16:41:08 GMT; Path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 16:41:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=35
Location: https://x.x.x.x/secure/login?__uri=/secure/login&

curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'x.x.x.x'
```

Comment: Should not the `wget` be requested to the public IP like `public_ip:18080`?

Comment: `18080` port I mentioned for example. I fixed the explanation. Actually public port is `56480` port.

Comment: Would you please run `curl -I --location http://x.x.x.x:56480` command? and let me know the result?

Comment: Thank you. I added its output at the end of the initial post.

Comment: Seems nginx returned 301 to this address `https://x.x.x.x/secure/login?__uri=/secure/login&`. Check nginx config.